# mmapping in Python C modules - any pitfalls to be aware of?

Tags: python, c, mmap, cpython, memory-mapping

I'm writing a Python module in C and I intend to mmap largeish blocks of memory (perhaps 500 MB). Is there anything about working in the same process space as the Python interpreter that I should be careful of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're fine.
On 32-bit systems, you could run out of virtual memory, or with virtual memory fragmentation not have a single chunk big enough to map as many huge files as you want. But that pitfall isn't particular to CPython.